# Java Applet open, edit and save image file

Tags: java, html, swing, deployment, applet

Imagine a scenario where I have an Apache server running on a server. Users from the internet come to the server and are greeted by a Java Applet which prompts them to select an image file from their computer. It then stamps the image file with a logo and overwrites the original image the user selected. I have this written as a desktop GUI app. Is there anyway to directly take my swing based application and run it on a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to directly take my swing based application and run it on a website?

Not on a website, but from a website.  Digitally sign the application Jar(s) and launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The app. will need to request `all-permissions` in the launch file.

Alternately to signing the code and requesting extended permissions, convert the I/O to use the equivalent JNLP API services.  The user will be prompted at run-time as to whether to allow the action.  See the sand-boxed [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for how that looks and feels.

Comment: +1, for the answer :-) , thought sometimes the major issue arises for the first time users to sign the .jar files :(, as I get access to my computer, I be on it to see, if I  had saved the method to this thingy. I will try provide the links likewise for the same.

Comment: Signing an applet is impossssssible.

Comment: That is incorrect.  Either that or I have done 'impossible' things many times.

Comment: @MohammadAdib : Here try this [link](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/signJARfiles.txt), that's how I signed my JAR Files once to learn this thingy, when I made this [small application](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/tables/tables/bin/tableapplet.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dear Friend here is an GUI that provides user interface to edit images...refer through it
/* Arpana */
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ConvolveApp extends JFrame {
  CPanel displayPanel;

  JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

  public ConvolveApp() {
    super();
    Container container = getContentPane();

    displayPanel = new CPanel();
    container.add(displayPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel
        .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

    sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
    sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
    blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
    edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(sharpenButton);
    panel.add(blurringButton);
    panel.add(edButton);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
     //setSize(100,100);
    setSize(displayPanel.getWidth()+50, displayPanel.getHeight() );
    setVisible(true); 
  }
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ConvolveApp();
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

      if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) {
        displayPanel.sharpen();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) {
        displayPanel.blur();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(edButton)) {
        displayPanel.edgeDetect();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
        displayPanel.reset();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      }
    }
  }
}

class CPanel extends JLabel {
  Image displayImage;

  BufferedImage biSrc;

  BufferedImage biDest; // Destination image is mandetory.

  BufferedImage bi; // Only an additional reference.

  Graphics2D big;

  CPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    loadImage();
    setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
    createBufferedImages();
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void loadImage() {
    displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Desert.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
    }
    if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
      System.out.println("No jpg file");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void createBufferedImages() {
    biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    big = biSrc.createGraphics();
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

    biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  }

  public void sharpen() {
    float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void blur() {
    float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
        0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

    public void edgeDetect() {
    float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f };

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void reset() {
    big.setColor(Color.black);
    big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    paintComponent(g);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```